# How open activity from Dialog, if app in onPause state?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have Dialog whith this option:

```
getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

And if my app is minimized, this dialog opens anyway. And if i press accept button in this dialog, I want open app. I tried:

```
if (AppContext.PAUSE_NOW) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SeDiDriverClient.class);
     mContext.startActivity(intent);
   }
```

like with notification, but it not helped. How do it?

**EDIT:**

I found this, and it helped

```
Intent startActivity = new Intent();
                        startActivity.setClass(mContext, xxx.class);
                        startActivity.setAction(xxx.class.getName());
                        startActivity.setFlags(
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                        mContext.startActivity(startActivity);
```

But if another app is opened, it not worck